# Cannot retrieve PDF document more than one time

Tags: java, spring, inputstream

I'm having real trouble debugging this controller:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Controller {

  private final UseCase useCase;

  public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getDocument() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = useCase.getDocument();

    StreamingResponseBody streamingResponse = out -> {
      IOUtils.copy(in, out);
      out.flush();
      out.close();
    };

    in.close();

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
        .body(streamingResponse);
  }
}
```

This is the use case:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UseCase {

  private final Repository repository;

  public InputStream getDocument() throws IOException {
      return repository.getDocument();
  }  
}
```

this is my repository:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Repository {

  private final Client client;

  public InputStream getDocument() throws IOException {
    return client.getDocument().getInputStream();
  }
}
```

and this, my client (which uses SpringFramework's RestTemplate):

```
@FeignClient(name = "my-client", url = "${url}")
public interface Client {

  @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
  InputStreamResource getDocument();

}
```

I have no trouble obtaining the PDF on the first request, but the following ones fail to do so, although the document is correctly retrieved in the controller and no error is shown in the application. I have no clue on what to do.

Comment: You can read `InputStream` only once. `useCase.getDocument()` should create new `InputStream` for every request

Comment: @geobreze I know, and I create new ones with every request...

Comment: Could you share an exception or code of `getDocument` method?

Comment: @geobreze I just edited

Comment: Do you get any error on second request or just empty response?

Comment: @geobreze no error. It returns a corrupt PDF. It is like the application applies some encoding to the inputstream, which corrupts the content. But I cannot guess why since the first request always works correctly...

Comment: Could you debug data on each step. Ex: Is data correct when *client.getDocument().getInputStream()* return?

Comment: @luanvu I already did that. Data is always correct, even at controller's return statement

Comment: Apparently using `InputStreamResource` instead of `StreamingResponseBody` works, which is fine for me, but I'd like to know why `StreamingResponseBody` fails...